# insert failed: Error: Title is required

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I'm trying to add an object to an object array that is a key in a collection entry with the following code, but I'm getting a weird response "insert failed: Error: Title is required". I'm using simple schema/autoform on meteor.

Has anyone encountered this before (and have a solution)?

```
Template.dashboard.events({
  'click .requestinvite'(e,t) {
    Posts.insert({ _id : $(e.currentTarget).attr('_id')},
    {$push: { invitesRequested : {username : Meteor.userId()} }}
  );
}
});
```

Here is the relevant Simple Schema in coffeescript

```
Schemas.Posts = new SimpleSchema
    title:
        type:String
        max: 60
        optional: true

    content:
        type: String
        optional: false
        autoform:
            rows: 5

    createdAt:
        type: Date
        autoValue: ->
            if this.isInsert
                new Date()

    updatedAt:
        type:Date
        optional:true
        autoValue: ->
            if this.isUpdate
                new Date()

    invitesRequested:
        type: [Object]
        optional: true
        defaultValue: []


    owner:
        type: String
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
        autoValue: ->
            if this.isInsert
                Meteor.userId()
        autoform:
            options: ->
                _.map Meteor.users.find().fetch(), (user)->
                    label: user.emails[0].address
                    value: user._id
```

Comment: Your simple schema must have a title that is required

Comment: Yeah, seems like simple schema is blocking insert, you need to permit title.

Comment: please post your SimpleSchema here. Provide adequate details so that we are not wasting time on your question.

Comment: @AnkurSoni added relevant simpleschema above

Answer (score 1):

First of all as per proper javascript assignment standards, you are doing blunder in your code.

What if your code is hacked and the click event is called without any id assigned?

Your code must be as follows.

```
Template.dashboard.events({
  'click .requestinvite'(e,t) {
    var id = $(e.currentTarget).attr('_id');
    if(id){
    Posts.insert(
        { 
            _id : id
        },
        {   
            $push: { 
                    invitesRequested : {username : Meteor.userId()} 
                }
        }
    );
    } else {
        //do something here when you don't have id here, or the `click` event is hacked on UI to work without id'
    }
}
});
```

Since your SimpleSchema is giving error regarding `title` field, if it is not mandatory, then kindly use `optional : true` at the point of defining `title` field.

e.g.

```
title: {
    type: String,
    label: "Title",
    optional: true   //<---- do this
}
```

> **NOTE**: By default, all keys are required. Set `optional: true` to change that.

Comment: this results in the following error

   'insert failed: Error: Content is required'

Comment: The chain of events is evident now, it appears its trying to create a new addition to Posts? I'm trying to push to the invitesRequested value array within an existing entry in Posts, why is trying to create a new Posts entry instead? Should I be using a different function instead of insert?

Comment: It is a humble request to accept my answer if it helped you achieve your answer. Accepting answer motivates us to answer more and more people leading them to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was using Posts.update instead. But Ankur Soni's post lead me in the right direction to troubleshoot this down.